# pypyodbc - Invalid cursor state when executing stored procedure in a loop

Tags: python, sql-server, pypyodbc

I have a python program which uses pypyodbc to interact with MSSQL database.  A stored procedure is created in MSSQL and is run via python.  If I execute the stored procedure only once (via python), there are no problems.  However, when it is executed multiple times within a for loop, I get the following error:

pypyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('24000', '[24000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Invalid cursor state')

My python code details are below:

```
connection_string_prod = 'Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=PSCSQCD1234.TEST.AD.TEST.NET\SQLINS99,2222;Database=Test;Uid=python;Pwd=python;'

connection_prod = pypyodbc.connect(connection_string_prod)

cursor_prod = connection_prod.cursor()

get_files_to_load_query = "Get_Files_To_Load"

files_to_load = cursor_prod.execute(get_files_to_load_query)

for file_name in files_to_load:
    load_query = "Load_Query_Stored_Proc @File_Name = '" + file_name + "'"
    cursor_prod.execute(load_query)

cursor_prod.commit()
cursor_prod.close()
connection_prod.close()
```

In some posts it was suggested to use "SET NOCOUNT ON" at the top of the SQL stored procedure.  I've done that already and it did not help with this issue.

Below is a code of a simple stored procedure that is causing the issue:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test]
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

INSERT INTO Test(a)
SELECT 1
```

Why executing the stored procedure within a for loop **only** causes an issue?

Please advise.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a cursor in the stored proc? Can you show the stored procedure code?

Comment: I don't have a cursor within the stored proc.  Included sample stored proc that is causing the issue within updated post.

Comment: Not sure if it is the best solution, but I was able to resolve my own problem  by creating a separate connection and having connection1 fetch a list of files to load and connection2 call the stored procedure to do the actual loading within the for loop.  If it is not clear, and it will help anyone, I can provide the updated working code.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `cursor_prod` values to control the `for` loop and then using that same cursor object *inside* the loop to run the stored procedure, thus invalidating the previous state of the cursor for controlling the loop. The first iteration of the loop is where the cursor gets overwritten, which is why you don't encounter the error until you try to go through the loop a second time.

You don't need to create a second *connection*, but you do need to use a second *cursor* to execute the stored procedure. Or, you could use `.fetchall` to stuff all of the file names into a `files_to_load` *list* and then iterate over that list, freeing up the cursor to run the stored procedure.

Comment: Gord - thank you for your explanation/suggestions.  I did add .fetchall() and there is no longer a need for a 2nd connection.  You solved the problem!